# Do two 4-port graphics card work together to display 8 monitors as one?

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors

I'm thinking of buying [two 4-port graphics cards](https://www.digitec.ch/en/s1/product/gigabyte-gt-740-oc-1gb-starter-graphics-cards-2735631?tagIds=76).

I have a simple question actually: will these 2 cards, that allow me to connect 8 monitors to one PC, operate as one, allowing me to use 8 monitors as one?

Comment: It depends on the OS.

Comment: I can basically install any OS, but say Windows 8.1 or 10?

Comment: This will require you to enable "activate all displays" within the Nvidia Control Panel.

Comment: Related: [How can I extend the desktop across 8 VGA monitors so they operate as one large monitor from one PC?](http://superuser.com/questions/1169742/how-can-i-extend-the-desktop-across-8-vga-monitors-so-they-operate-as-one-large/1169747#1169747) and [How do I setup 3D Vision Surround?](http://nvidia.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/2667)

Answer (score 2):

> Do two 4-port graphics card work together to display 8 monitors as one?

Two four port graphics cards, each being able to output to all four ports simultaneously could work. So that is a 'Yes'.

There are a few things which can mess this up though:

1. The OS needs to support multiple graphics cards.
2. The OS needs to support the drivers for multiple graphics cards. Often trivial if you use identical cards. Not always the case it you use a Matrox and and AMD card, or and Intel and a Nvida card. In windows this support is present since windows 7. XP and older do not support it.
3. The OS needs to be able to output to 8 monitors. A modern windows can handle 8 monitors (and I think so can BSD, Linux or OSX), but there are limits. IIRC there are posts here on [SU] where a perfectly sensible 32 screen configuration was build which exceeded build in limits.
4. Lastly, make sure you have a graphics card able to output to 4 monitors at the same time. Mine (A GTX960) can do that. But I had to look before I bought since many 4 ports cards only output to 3 ports at max, making you pick and choose.  (note that 6 output cards generally allow you to use all 6 ports though).

Answer (score 0):

No you can't, whatever OS you gonna use.

> GT 740 Display Support: Multi Monitor - 3 Displays

The included hardware, even if you have 4 ports, can't handle more than 3 of them. E.g the DVI and HDMI outputs of some cards have the same clock, which is switched by the GPU chip to use one port or the other, but not both.

So, in your case, you'll get a maximum of 6 displays.

[Source](http://www.geforce.com/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-gt-740/specifications)

---

Edit :

Seems that it works [for this guy](http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/forum/id-2396219/gt740-multi-monitor-desktop-area-issue.html) but with the 2 Gb version (Edit 2)

You'll then just have to define your monitors setting in the nVidia control panel, if you're using windows.

Just, don't except high framerates, or putting SLI between cards !

Comment: When I check the [specs of the graphics cards](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=5093#sp) from my opening post, I see they support "multi view: 4"

My motherboard supports SLI.. so if the cards do too (I have to figure out if Nvideo sublicenses this technology to Gigabyte) then it should work, no?

Comment: No. You do not need SLI. SLI disables the outputs on all but the primary card. Second (and third, ...) card are memrely computable units. If you want to use outputs on a non primary card then do not enable SLI mode.

Answer (score 0):

I have a 12 monitor setup with

1. 2 NVIDIA GEForce 730 1x PCIE ([https://www.amazon.com/ASUS-GeForce-Graphics-Single-Slot-Passive/dp/B0B5B7J74M/ref=sr_1_10?crid=30HYMV3OHXWZS&keywords=nvidia+730&qid=1684686218&sprefix=nvidia+730%2Caps%2C106&sr=8-10](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0B5B7J74M))
2. 1 Radeon 6650 [https://www.amazon.com/XFX-Speedster-SWFT210-Graphics-RX-665X8DFDY/dp/B09ZLRDMXX/ref=sr_1_4?crid=16YBW4MM27GHE&keywords=radeon+6650&qid=1684686329&sprefix=radeon+6650%2Caps%2C99&sr=8-4&ufe=app_do%3Aamzn1.fos.18ed3cb5-28d5-4975-8bc7-93deae8f9840](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B09ZLRDMXX)

An older driver is available for the 730 (I think 473.x.x) and there is absolutely no conflict with Radeon Adrenalin. I'm running windows 11 profesional. Gaming is not really possible on the NVIDIA controlled monitors, but I'm able to play Myth of Empires and Ark on the Radeon controlled monitors